(nextjs) CORS error when redirrected to the Auth0 login page
I'm using auth0 to allow user to go to the admin mode of his Nextjs website.
Doing so, if the user add /Admin to the url he's redirected to the auth0 login page.
The problem is, just before being redirected to the auth0 login page, i got these errors:
Access to fetch at 'https://dev-***********.us.auth0.com/authorize?**********' 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login?_rsc=1siqz') 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

then:
GET https://dev-*********.us.auth0.com/authorize?*********::ERR_FAILED

finally:
app-bootstrap.js:33 Failed to fetch RSC payload for http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login. Falling back to browser navigation. TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at fetchServerResponse (navigate-reducer.js:58:27)
    at eval (_class_private_field_loose_key.js:136:106)
    at Object.task (prefetch-reducer.js:30:38)
    at PromiseQueue.processNext (prefetch-reducer.js:81:186)
    at PromiseQueue.enqueue (prefetch-reducer.js:45:76)
    at createLazyPrefetchEntry (_class_private_field_loose_key.js:136:49)
    at getOrCreatePrefetchCacheEntry (_class_private_field_loose_key.js:87:12)
    at navigateReducer_noPPR (router-reducer.js:102:82)
    at clientReducer (action-queue.js:25:61)
    at Object.action (use-reducer-with-devtools.js:150:55)
    at runAction (use-reducer-with-devtools.js:56:38)
    at dispatchAction (use-reducer-with-devtools.js:113:9)
    at Object.dispatch (use-reducer-with-devtools.js:145:40)
    at eval (hooks-client-context.shared-runtime.js:130:21)
    at eval (app-call-server.js:159:16)
    at eval (app-call-server.js:283:21)
    at startTransition (index.js:2597:25)
    at Object.replace (app-call-server.js:281:44)
    at eval (app-router-announcer.js:33:24)
    at Object.startTransition (index.js:2597:25)
    at eval (app-router-announcer.js:29:24)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (index.js:21102:23)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (index.js:23154:7)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23406:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23485:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23485:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23485:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23485:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23404:9)
    at recursivelyTraverseReconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23386:5)
    at reconnectPassiveEffects (index.js:23485:9)

Once in the Auth0 login page, if i input my logins information and click 'login', i'm redirected to the Admin mode, but my cookie is instantly deleted...
I'm using the quistart guide of Auth0 (i've reconfigurated 4 times now) with this route.js file:
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export const GET = handleAuth();

My redirect file (/Admin/page.tsx):
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';


export default async function AdminPage() {
    const session = await getSession();
    const user = session?.user;

    if (!user)
        redirect ('/api/auth/login')
    else
        redirect ('/')
}

I've dig into a lot of post about this problem, (changing next.config.mjs file to add headers) but nothing resolve my issue.
Any ideas?
Edit:
At the difference of the problem mentionned in this post: Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS, my /Admin/page.tsx page already redirect the user to the login page. And i'm receiving the cookie of connection, it just get deleted instantly after redirection to my website.

This question is similar to: Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@HeikoTheißen done !

The user must be redirected to dev-***********.us.auth0.com/authorize as well, instead of fetching this page.

Isn't the purpose of nextjs-auth0?
